# How to create transparent activity in android programmatically?

Tags: android, android-activity

I need to create a transparent activity in android programmatically. I was able to achieve this using XML (theme) but I need to do this programmatically.

I tried below code in onCreate but this doesn't work.

```
getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create custom Style and use it as below inside Activity:

```
@Override
public void setTheme(int resId){

super.setTheme(R.style.Theme_AppCompat_Translucent);

}
```